# Rails JS respond to create action fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having trouble getting the current page to reload, after posting a remote form in Rails 4, to create join object in my db. It works fine for another model association in my app, but not here....

View Form:

## select from dropdown which collection to assign to:

```
<% unless current_user == nil %>
<div class="btn-group pull-right">
  <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    Collect
<span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <% current_user.collections.each do |collection| %>
    <% unless  CollectionPiece.where(:collection_id => collection.id, :piece_id => @piece.id).exists? %>
    <li><%= link_to raw("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></i>  #{collection.title}"), collection_pieces_path(:collection_piece => {:piece_id => @piece.id, :collection_id => collection.id}), :remote => true, class: "", :method => :post %></li>
    <% end %>
     <% end %>
        <li><%= link_to raw("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-th-large'></i>  New Collection"), new_collection_path, :class => "" %></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
 <% end %>
```

Collection Piece controller:

```
class CollectionPiecesController < ApplicationController


after_action :collection_email, only: :create


def create
    @collection_piece = CollectionPiece.create(collection_piece_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @collection_piece.save
        format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Collection was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Collection was not successfully created.' }
      end
    end
end

def destroy
    @collection_piece = CollectionPiece.where(collection_piece_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @collection_piece.first.destroy
        format.js { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Collection was successfully destroyed.' }
      else
        format.js { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Collection was not successfully destroyed.' }
      end
    end
end

def collection_email
    @profile = current_user.profile
    @piece = Piece.find(params[:collection_piece][:piece_id])
    @collection = Collection.find(collection_piece_params[:collection_id])
    UserMailer.collection_email(@profile.user, @piece, @collection).deliver
     end

   private

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def collection_piece_params
  params.require(:collection_piece).permit(:piece_id, :collection_id)
end



end
```

create.js.erb:

```
console.log("why you no work?");
location.reload();
```

Hope you can help, let me know if you need more info?

Comment: Are you sure you want `format.html` in your `create` action and not `format.js`?

Comment: Why would the page reload after a remote call?

Comment: @ptd oops. sorry it's format.js

Comment: @DaveNewton so that the dropdown options are updated

Comment: But... you're redirecting? Wouldn't you want to send the data back, and re-fill the options? It's not clear what you're trying to do, or how you think you're trying to do it. If you want to refresh the page (which seems odd to me) then you'd need to have a success handler that set window.location or something. But yuck.

Comment: Yeah it's yuck, I should just be reloading the form partial. Don't need to send the data back, a flash message would be good. Looking at the stack trace it seems to hit the controller create action as JS but then re-direct to the original show view again as JS...